# Shunts and Ammeters in Automotive Applications - High Output Car Stereo

Tags: shunt

Good Day EESE. After reading a lot of info and forums (on other sites) regarding shunts, and as everyone here seems pretty intelligent, as I only went to a public school ;) possibly you may answer this question. I have a competition car stereo system and I'm looking to add an ammeter to my vehical. My alternator puts out 320 amps max (180 at idle). The amps in my car will, when required, deliver 4000 watts RMS to my subs/speakers. I bought a 300A / 75mv ammeter to affix permanetly in the car (it displays voltage as well). Knowing/learning that shunts should only be utilized continuously at ~60% there capacity, I bought a 500 amp shunt at 75mv. Will this work? The ammeter called for a 300 amp shunt however I want to allow as much current as possible with as little power lost to heat... and of course I do not want to starve my system with inadequate current I.e. voltage or amperage. I do appreciate any guidence or any other information you may kindly suggest.
Very Respectfully,
Justin

---

Thank you for all the responses, if not for you all id sill be lost. So thank you and I did purchas another ammeter to match the shunt, thank you for answering the question PlasmaHH and Bruce :).  Just to clarify Andy, I only push the system at high levels during competition. I don't disturb neighborhoods like many others do. The "public school" comment was a joke, however I did go to one. Back to the topic,  As far as the many other amps, I have 4. like stated above, I have the ability to push 4000 watts of continous power, RMS. Some may say that's 8000 watts max but I disagree with that logic. Real world, everyday driving, I'm pushing maybe 300 watts RMS or continuous, however I want the Power when needed. Last SPL competition I hit 156.4 - legally. Thanks again all!!!

---

Thank you for all the responses, if not for you all id sill be lost. So thank you and I did purchas another ammeter to match the shunt, thank you for answering the question PlasmaHH and Bruce :).  Just to clarify Andy, I only push the system at high levels during competition. I don't disturb neighborhoods like many others do. The "public school" comment was a joke, however I did go to one. Back to the topic,  As far as the many other amps, I have 4. like stated above, I have the ability to push 4000 watts of continous power, RMS. Some may say that's 8000 watts max but I disagree with that logic. Real world, everyday driving, I'm pushing maybe 300 watts RMS or continuous, however I want the Power when needed. Last SPL competition I hit 156.4 - legally. Thanks again all!!!
                                                                                                                                                                         UPDATED!  Please any assistance would be appreciated.                                        So, I finally got around and installed my 500amp 75mv shunt, with the matching ammeter/voltmeter display combo, installed on the negative power side. I have all my negative car cable(s) connected to one side of the shunt. On the other side of the shunt, only 1 large wire going to the neg battery terminal. Here's where lies my problem... with the ignition on, but the car is NOT running, I can see my ammeters values (digits) respectively increase when I turn on my accesories I.e. the heater fan, lights, etc... However; as soon as I start the car, the amp values go to zero, even with all my accesories on. My 'goal' is to see what draw my car is consuming. I've tried several configurations, just messing around, to see if I might stumble across a solution... to no resolve. I'm quite mystified. Wires connected are: Neg / pos wires for voltmeter connected straight to battery w/switch to turn off/on. Neg (black) wire on the ammeter connected to battery neg side of shunt. Ammeter Yellow wire connected to car chasis side of shunt (along with all my other neg lines). Ammeter Red wire connected directly to positive battery terminal. Just can't figure out what gives??? Can a shunt be installed backward (Does it matter, the power return flow? Basically keep all the connected wires the same, just 'flip' the shunt?) Does the voltmeters power need to be isolated? (I've read in other sources that it doesn't, just needs to be between 4.5v and 30v. (There was no instruction manual) Does it matter that I have a 4000 amp battery and a 320 amp alternator? Is that what's throwing this all off?  Thank you all for any assistance! V/R justin

Comment: "I only went to a public school" I went to a public school too, and I think i'm pretty smart!

Comment: how continuous are these many hundreds of amps? What is the "average" current expected to be? That is the real measure of what the shunt should be able to handle (continuously anyway).

Comment: Note that the ampmeter converts the 0-75mV it is reading into a fixed amount of amps, so when you have one of these LED on PCB things you need a matching ampmeter.

Comment: It would be cheaper to use headphones and far less annoying to other road users. Watts RMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd Update: With the assistance of those on this forum (thank you), and with my trial and error, I thought it be fair to share what I have 'learned', in consideration that another like me encounters the same head scratching dilema as I regarding the wiring of shunts, or moreso the ammeters reading, what it actually means (verse what I assumed/expected)...
To set up my scenario... I recently installed a shunt, which I then wired to an ammeter that I installed in my car. My intent was to see how much current/draw, or amps, were being consumed in totality by my vehical, most specifically when my stereo is on (but even with it not on as well).
My initial dillema: This weekend, after installing the shunt on the negative side, and after wiring it per the multitude of models/diagrams I googled, I was not receiving a value other than 0 on the digital display when the car was running, it only displayed values/data when it was not running when turning on acceceries, and I was certain I had it all wired up correctly. (The voltmeter worked just fine though (after calibration with my multimeter) - a true 14.6 to 15.1 volts with car running).
What I have learned: Monday, driving home on the freeway (yesterday) I turned up my stereo and all my acceseries to there max, to see if I could get a reaction on my ammeters display. With the tunes very loud, and as I played a song with continual rolling bass, I got some feed back. I noticed that periodically my ammeter would show 1, 5, 17, etc... amps. When I got off the freeway and came to a stop (the alternator is not spinning as it once was) I noticed the ammeter jumped considerably higher, up to 90 amps at one point for a brief second (as my alternators regulator made 'adjustments'), then settled back around an average of 30 amps while driving thru the back streets. Again, the alternator was spinning more than when I was at a stop, but obviously less than when I was on the freeway. 
What I gathered... The ammeter was showing the current being created by the alternator. More specifically, it was showing the differance in current that the battery was not able to provide to my power hungry consuming amps (and everything else that was on). So, in theory, if I have a battery that is optimal, and performs what it states (4000 amps / 5000 amps at peak), what my ammeter was showing was the difference in power created by my alternator thus required to satisfy my amps (or really - maintain full battery charge). If my battery was delivering 4000 amps, and my ammeter showed a value of 30 amps, I interpret this as my vehicle, in it entirety, was consuming roughly 4030 amps.
SIDE NOTE: This is good data as my AGM battery (that cost $600) has a lifecycle of 1000 charges. Meaning, as I discussed this with the manufacturer because I was concerned that 1000 cycles is really only approximatly 3 years if I start/run my car everyday. The manufacture said my battery can be nearly depleated of stored energy 1000 times before it becomes 'old' or less efficiant. If the battery is only depleated say 5 or 10% each cycle then I can get 4 or 5000 cycle(s) meaning the battery can last many years longer. (I didn't do the math, but you get my point).
Back to the subject: What this all meant to me, the closer my value was to zero, the difference displayed on my ammeter, was the power/amps required of my car's battery that was being subsidized by my alternator. My battery is closer to a full charge, or maintaining a more full charge, when the value is at 0. This is a good sign as well, my battery doesn't drain much making it last longer, also a good investment as I spent $650 on a HighOutput 320 amp alternator. (its a HO Hairpin Stator alternator... it produces 180 amps at idle, or 700 rpms, anyways...
Thinking Deeper (hence my public school joke above ;) This still doesn't satisfy my initial question, or assumption/expectation. "What draw is my car consuming in its entirety? From both the battery and alternator?" I still have not the answer...
There are too many variables I.e. The biggest unknown -True battery power being stored/delivered, then maybe temperature, shunt and ammeter calibration, etc... For this scenario let's say temperature and calibration are pretty good, I'm still left with unknown True battery power that's at my dispose.
Out of curiosity, this morning before I left for work, I switched my shunt/ammeter reading leads to see what would happen. With the car running, but before turning anything or accessery on, I noticed my ammeter was showing 8 amps a few minutes, later it dropped to around 3 amps and maintained. This was obviously different than yesterday, as I was only showing a 0 value. Then I set up a test. I kept my test the same as the day before, everything on, stereo blaring the same song. I noticed on the freeway 1, 5, 8 amps. (there was always a value > or = to 1. At stop lights my values jumped around from 30 thru 80 amps (rpms were low). At slower speeds my values were around 15 to 20 amps. I then turned all my accesories off and displayed was 8 amps for 20 seconds or so, then settled/maintained at 4 amps.
What I deduced: Vice what I observed yesterday - my ammeter only showed a value/charge when the battery dropped below its full charge, today I believe I witnessed what my alternator was putting out to maintain a full battery charge! (I liked this 'setting' or wiring much better as there is always activity being displayed. Not like yesterday, when a value is only displayed when the battery is below 100%. (as I don't blare the stereo often, I then would always see a 0 value.
Although I'm happy that I have data that I can interpret, even though I'm not displaying total current consumption as initially desired, I do have a better knowledge of my cars electrical state. What would be nice. To have digital ammeter that was able to display negative values. With that I would then be able to know what's going on at values below zero, without having to switch around the wiring. (I'll keep looking for one, but till then I'll leave the wiring set up as is, opposite what the wiring diagrams suggest/show.)
Hope I was able to help someone. Lord knows I've invested many hours looking for this info.
Although realizing having my voltmeter calibrated close is most critical to calculating my current (It was off about 2 volts) as the voltage takes a huge role relative in determining amperage, If anyone has a suggestion on how to calibrate my ammeter, using my multimeter, I'm all ears. I know I could go to Autozone or buy a current meter, if so be the case.  (if the ammeter is only off by 2 then that's a less big deal... I supose)
Take Care and have a Great Day!
V/R
Justin...

Answer (score 2):

A shunt is just a low value resistor that (like all resistors) drops a voltage proportional to the current flowing through it.

A 500A 75mV shunt drops 45mV at 300A, so your 300A @ 75mV ammeter will only read 60% of the true value. You need to match the shunt to the meter.